# jQuery scope & iOS

Tags: jquery, ios4

I have a simple function in jQuery and I wanted to test out the scope.

```
$(function() {
     function showTest() {
          alert('test');
     }

     showTest(); // within scope so its OK
});

$(function() {
     showTest(); // out of scope
}

showTest(); // out of scope
```

How can I reference the showTest() that is within the first jQuery statement? I'm trying to access the showTest using **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** but I cannot seem to hit it. I've tried both the out of scope methods and can't think of another way to reference the method inside the jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolating variables and functions from outside code is what anonymous functions are *supposed* to do. If you want to run `showTest` outside of your anonymous function, you have to remove the anonymous function:

```
function showTest() {
     alert('test');
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    (function() {
       showTest(); // ok
    })();

    showTest(); // ok
});
```

Comment: what if its wrapped inside $(document).ready(function() { ... jquery stuff here ... }); how can I get around that? yes I have provided a basic example but that showTest does something intricate inside that anonymous function

Comment: Again: the entire point of an anonymous function is to isolate variables. If you don't want them isolated, don't put them there. Your functions can be declared outside of `$(document).ready...` and called inside of it without causing problems.

Comment: Can you provide me a basic example of using jquery without $(document).ready(function(){}) or the equivalent $(function(){})? The reason I ask is that without this statement the jquery won't execute. If that's the case are you saying its not possible to call a method inside jquery as its an anonymous function? It seems to be the case, ill think of a different approach. Thanks.

Comment: I understand what you were trying to say and thought about what to do so I'm separating some of my vars outside of the anonymous function that I need which is manipulated inside the jquery anonymous functions. Cheers.